# GraphicsMode configuration for NokiaX via MonoGame

Tags: c#, opengl-es-2.0, monogame, opentk, nokiax

As described [here](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/535245) I am having difficulty porting my existing working Android games, developed using MonoGame, to Nokia X.

OpenTK does not appear to be able to detect the device capabilities properly, or something similar:

```
OpenTK.Platform.Android.EglException: Failed to find a valid GraphicsMode configuration
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGraphicsMode.ChooseConfig (Javax.Microedition.Khronos.Egl.EGLDisplay display) [0x0035c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGraphicsMode.cs:186
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGraphicsMode.Initialize (Javax.Microedition.Khronos.Egl.EGLDisplay display, Int32 version) [0x0000a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGraphicsMode.cs:223
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGraphicsContext.Init (OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode mode, IWindowInfo win, IGraphicsContext sharedContext, Int32 major, GraphicsContextFlags flags) [0x000a9] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGraphicsContext.cs:114
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGraphicsContext..ctor (OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode mode, IWindowInfo window, IGraphicsContext sharedContext, GLContextVersion glesVersion, GraphicsContextFlags flags) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGraphicsContext.cs:88
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGraphicsContext.CreateGraphicsContext (OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsMode mode, IWindowInfo window, IGraphicsContext sharedContext, GLContextVersion glVersion, GraphicsContextFlags flags) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGraphicsContext.cs:50
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView.CreateContext () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGameView.cs:314
  at OpenTK.Platform.Android.AndroidGameView.CreateFrameBuffer () [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/OpenGLES/Android/AndroidGameView.cs:165
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameWindow.CreateFrameBuffer () [0x0003f] in /Users/paulharman/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework/Android/AndroidGameWindow.cs:164
```

I'm asking for an 800x480 screen (which is the native screen size of the device) and Color mode (8,8,8,8) - although MonoGame itself tries various fallbacks to simpler bit depths, stencils etc. but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone else seen this issue and have an idea of what might be wrong?

I am using the tip of MonoGame (develop branch) as of the time of writing. Xamarin details:

=== Xamarin Studio ===

Version 4.2.3 (build 54)
Installation UUID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.6 ((no/9b58377)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 theme: Raleigh
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 302060000

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build 5A3005

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 7.0.6.168 (Business Edition)
Hash: 2ed9bc9
Branch: 
Build date: 2014-21-01 06:33:05-0500

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 4.10.1 (Business Edition)
Android SDK: /Users/paulharman/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        1.6   (API level 4)
        2.1   (API level 7)
        2.2   (API level 8)
        2.3   (API level 10)
        3.1   (API level 12)
        3.2   (API level 13)
        4.0   (API level 14)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.1   (API level 16)
        4.2   (API level 17)
        4.4   (API level 19)
Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 402030054
Git revision: f3fd2a8582693cd1728166bcfc17056235cb5b05
Build date: 2014-02-03 17:26:56+0000
Xamarin addins: b992974cc7bee7713bba6abaf2b4fac94e67dd1c

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.9.1
Darwin HOSTNAME 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0
    Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013
    root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: You should probably file a bug in the Xamarin bug tracker. They are the authors of AndroidGameView so they might have a better idea on what is going on here.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is slightly out of date, but I recently received the same error on Android Virtual Device, so I figured out that I can post how I solved it.

Have you tried to use hardware GPU in the Android Virtual Device settings? [open Android Emulator Manager, pick your AVD and click edit, then make sure that the checkbox next to "Use Host GPU" is ticked]

I had the same error with my game, but then I turned this option on and it works perfectly without any flaws. I'm using MonoGame in my development, but maybe this will work for you too.

I'm not sure if Nokia X emulator has this hardware GPU support though.

Comment: I never did figure this one out, and since the Nokia X project is dead, I didn't bother trying. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to this report, Paul kindly collaborated with Nokia to analyze the suspected issues mentioned in the original question.

As a result of the investigation, we mutually concluded that the specific findings above from the app are not Nokia X specific, yet are reproducing on other Android devices as well.

I recommend this issue to be closed.

Petro Soininen
Head of Developer Support
Nokia Developer Relations

Comment: I concur that this does not appear to be a Nokia X issue. I still have the problem, but evidence suggests that it is not related to the X.